# Find optimal binary search tree structure

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

In reference to the problem [HERE](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-24-optimal-binary-search-tree/), how can we find the structure of optimal binary search tree. 
Author says:

> In the above solutions, we have computed optimal cost only. The
>   solutions can be easily modified to store the structure of BSTs also.
>   We can create another auxiliary array of size n to store the structure
>   of tree. All we need to do is, store the chosen ‘r’ in the innermost
>   loop.

But above is not clear to me. Talking about loops, we start with chains of length 2,3 .. and so on.  So let us say we store the value or r for chain of length 3 and onwards. How does it depict or help in getting tree structure ?

Comment: Looking at the algorithm code, when you are done processing the innermost loop, the value of `r` that achieved the minimum cost is the one to be used as the root of the subtree and should be stored in the corresponding tree node.

Comment: And how to assign its left and right nodes ? Can you please fill in a little details

Comment: Mimick `cost = optCost(freq, i, r-1) + optCost(freq, r+1, j);` once the optimal `r` is found, you recurse on the left and right subintervals.